# stored procedure compiled with errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure where I am trying to take 2 input age and name
That will update the record in employee table.

But when I am compiling getting - compiled with errors

**Code :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_emp_age
(
    v_age in number;
    v_ename in varchar2(255 char);
) AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE employee
    SET
        eage = v_age
    WHERE
        ename = v_ename;

    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: Use `show errors` to view the compiler errors

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Got fix for it : need to make `varchar2(255 char)`  to `varchar2;`

Comment: Are you sure you want to ROLLBACK? That procedure won't have any effect with it ...

Answer (score 2):

- Remove the size from the data types in the signature.
- Use commas and not semi-colons between arguments in the signature.
- Don't `ROLLBACK` (else your query will perform the update and then immediately `ROLLBACK` the change doing lots of work for no effect and potentially rolling back prior chages).

Like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_emp_age
(
    v_age   in NUMBER,
    v_ename in VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE employee
    SET   eage = v_age
    WHERE ename = v_ename;
END;
/
```

You could also use `%TYPE` in the signature:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_emp_age
(
    v_age   in EMPLOYEE.EAGE%TYPE,
    v_ename in EMPLOYEE.ENAME%TYPE
) AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE employee
    SET   eage = v_age
    WHERE ename = v_ename;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f9d200d9165c5b7116f52999c1daac10)*